# asctec_drivers Error Reading Packet Header

Tags: ros, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i am trying to run the asctec_driver on my atom board via roslaunch ascrec_proc asctec_driver.launch.
i have set the port parameter and let the rest of them standard. Now i always get the following error message:

Timeout: 0 bytes available 3 bytes requested
Error Reading Packet Header: Resource temporarily unavailable
Read (-1):
Read failed

does someone can explain me that error ? i was checking all cable connections between the atom_board and the HL (connected with the three wires cable - AscTec Usb --> Atomboard Connection Cable) The cable is connected to UART1, therefore, we set the port to ttyUSB1 (but also tried ttyUSB0) is there anything else i had to do ??
Could it be that i need to install a new firmware or so?? we are using the asctec_pelican with ros the first time, we do not faund anything on the homepage of the ccny, hope that someone here can help us (:

EDIT: The connection via the XBEE to the DesktopPC works fine, autopilot runs on the PC.
Just if we connect the LL to the Atomboard nothing happens and we get that error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39868/asctec_drivers-error-reading-packet-header/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, the ccny drivers work with the Low Level Processor, i.e. you have to connect the serial cable to "LL serial 0" as shown in the manual.

[asctec_mav_framework](http://www.ros-org/asctec_mav_framework) works with the HL, but you have to flash it.

---

Originally posted by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) with karma: 390 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-26**:
ok thanks, and with what do i have to flash the HL ?

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2012-07-26**:
[www.ros.org/wiki/asctec_hl_firmware](http://www.ros.org/wiki/asctec_hl_firmware). But I would recommend having a look at both stacks (asctec_drivers and asctec_mav_framework) and figure out what is more suitable for you

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-26**:
ok thanks for your help